# Found a cateye strada computer on a trail. What to do?

Tags: bike-computer, trails

Should I let it where it was?
I know it's not an bike specific question, but maybe I can get good ideas.

Comment: Maybe put a notice at the trail entrance? Without the sensor, the head unit is pretty much useless.

Comment: If it were a more expensive bike computer with GNSS capabilities you could have looked at recorded tracks and found out where the person lives.

Comment: Is there a ranger station for this trail/area?

Comment: Aside - this is why you name your stuff.   Even as an adult, its a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend on where you live, but in the area where I live there are lost&found shops that keep lost items in stock in case the owner asks if a lost item was found.

Generally there's a small fee for the owner to retrieve a lost item. Probably far below the cost of a bike computer.

Of course if there's some easy way to find who lost the item, you could do them a service and try to find the owner, and give the computer for free (such as leaving a note near the area where the item was lost). But failing that, or if you attempted that and nobody contacted you, leave it at a lost&found shop.

Note you should never give the item away without an accurate description by the owner. For example, if the computer has an odometer, the owner most likely has a rough idea of the odometer reading. That can be used as a test if the claimed owner is the true owner.

Don't leave the computer on the trail. Then anyone can pick it up from there without even knowing the odometer reading! Instead, leave a note with your contact details.

Answer (score 2):

In most jurisdictions found items are not yours, and if the owner cannot be located, must legally be handed into the Police ( although a low value item such as this will be of little interest to most Police departments ).

Where I live local bike clubs use social media for all their communications, many misplaced items have been returned to their rightful owner through these pages, regardless of club membership.  Neighborhood social media pages and groups are also a common way to reconnect lost items and owners.

Depending how much effort you are prepared to put in, sometimes its best to leave it in an obvious place - like a trail entrance.  Several times I have seen posts on social media along the lines "I left my <Front wheel/throu axle etc> at the car park, went back an hour later and it was gone", and "I found a <Front wheel/throu axle etc> at the car park, if its yours message me"